# Class 'Aws\Sns\SnsClient' not found PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to send a text message using the Composer AWS SDK on PHP.

*PHP 7.2.11 (cli) (built: Oct 10 2018 02:39:52) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x8
6 ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.11, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies*

Got composer installed and installed the aws-sdk-php. Now when i run it, i literally get the infamous  error Class 'Aws\Sns\SnsClient' not found. I have tried all sorts of code samples including the one on the AWS sample documentation page. I do confirm that  i have re-run composer require aws/aws-sdk-php just to be doubly sure. Here's the output:

*Using version ^3.145 for aws/aws-sdk-php
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files*

This leads me  to believe that the sdk itself seems to be  missing or for some reasons the autoload.php is unable to find it.
Help anyone, must be a simple config that i am not seeing.

PHP Code:

```
  *<?php
  require 'E:\Bitnami\apps\phpmyadmin\htdocs\vendor\autoload.php';
 $params = array(
   'credentials' => array(
    'key' => 'XXXX',
    'secret' => 'XXXX',
    ),
   'region' => 'us-east-1', // < your aws from SNS Topic region
   'version' => 'latest'
  );
  $sns = new \Aws\Sns\SnsClient($params);*
```

Regards,

Ochen

Comment: Can you check in the vendor directory the AWS SDK was correctly pulled in?

Comment: oh yeah, i forgot to mention, i don't see the aws sdk file....

Comment: Did you run it in the `E:\Bitnami\apps\phpmyadmin\htdocs` directory?

Comment: Bingo spot on... mate !!! I didn't. Ok, i either have to run it again in the direcotryy or copy it from the earlier location.....

Comment: Run it in the directory, do not copy as this will not add it to the composer.lock :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the file is not in that vendor folder ensure the following:

- Write permissions exist for `E:\Bitnami\apps\phpmyadmin\htdocs` and its subfolders
- Run composer install (or require) in `E:\Bitnami\apps\phpmyadmin\htdocs`
- Check the composer.lock file for `E:\Bitnami\apps\phpmyadmin\htdocs` has the AWS SDK in it.

Comment: much better now: waiting for the text message, sent it to myself, hasn't arrived yet... object(Aws\Result)#119 (2) {
  ["data":"Aws\Result":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["MessageId"]=>
    string(36) "67564a90-c0f1-5442-8e00-1dea82913f18"
    ["@metadata"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["statusCode"]=>
      int(200)

Comment: still hasn't arrived, surely doesn't need a topic does it?

Comment: Nope according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sns-2010-03-31.html#publish you dont need a topic

Comment: found it, i was using the SMS Type as Promotional, changed it to Transactional, now works like a charm....